# Find id from other list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have two lists:

```
List<MasterData> masterDataList;
List<Job> jobList;
```

My classes look like this:

```
public class Job
{
    ...
    public int MasterDataId { get; set; } //foreign key
}
```

And:

```
public class MasterData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'd now like to iterate through my `jobList` and get all jobs which have one of the `MasterDataId` of all id's in `masterDataList`.
How can I do this with LINQ (to objects)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jobList.Where(job => masterDataList.Any(m => m.Id == job.MasterDataId));
```

Or more efficient way might be using a HashSet:

```
var masterIdList = new HashSet<int>(masterDataList.Select(m => m.Id));
var result = jobList.Where(job => masterIdList.Contains(job.MasterDataId));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
jobList.Where(j=>masterDataList.Any(m=>m.MasterDataId == j.Id))
```

Comment: this will not work ;) `(m=>m.MasterDataId == j.Id)` should be `(m=>m.Id == j.MasterDataId )`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to query like:

```
var items = jobList.Where(r => masterDataList.Any(t => t.Id == r.MasterDataId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ `Where` with `Any`:

```
var matching = jobList.Where(jl => masterDataList.Any(mdl => jl.MasterDataId == mdl.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = jobList.where(j => j.MasterDataId == 5);
```

Or

```
var result = from j in jobList where j.MasterDataId == 5 select j;
```